# Onclick Cancel not working properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, class

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!gotoPage}">
    <apex:param name="p1" value="{!Attachment.Id}" assignTo="{!deleteid}"/>
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Rforce_Ecare_Icons_STR,'Icons/Delete.png')}" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to proceed?');"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

`Onclick()` if I click `ok/cancel` both are same action called, if i click cancel that also called that `deleteid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your version two things happen at once. The commandlink triggers your delete action and seperately the image triggers the confirmation action. I think they should both be called from the commandlink. I think this may work for you:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!gotoPage}" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to proceed?');">
    <apex:param name="p1" value="{!Attachment.Id}" assignTo="{!deleteid}"/>
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Rforce_Ecare_Icons_STR,'Icons/Delete.png')}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Comment: Your welcome, happy to help.